# Host multiple apps with Django, mod_wsgi

Tags: virtualhost, django, mod-wsgi

I want to host two web apps using a same Apache server, and with IP address in the URL. Two apps are differentiated by their URLs. For example,

203.1.1.1/app1/
and
203.1.1.1/app2/

I'm using mod_wsgi with Apache. However, I'm able to access only one of the apps. How should the Virtual hosts be written in my httpd.conf file?

Thank you!

Comment: can't you use dns names instead of accessing via ip address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [fine manual](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), adding a `WSGIScriptAlias` for each app.

```
 <Directory "/usr/local/wsgi/scripts">
 Order allow,deny 
 Allow from all
 </Directory>

 WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/app1.wsgi
 WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /usr/local/wsgi/scripts/app2.wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion finally helped me to solve this! :)